# How solve a logical statement in Gatsby (react JS)?

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, gatsby

I can't seem to wrap my head around a logical statement in react.js...

here is my code:

```
<li key={item.title}>
  {item.child_items 
    ? <Link 
      activeClassName="active"
      partiallyActive={true}
      aria-haspopup="true" 
      to={`/${item.slug}`}>{item.title}</Link> //reference line

    : <Link to={`/${item.slug}`}>{item.title}</Link>
  }
</li>
```

This part is working.  What I am trying to accomplish is that if item.title is "home" then the reference line (commented above) would have be `to={`/`}>{item.title}</Link>`

I think i need a function here that renders `{`/`}` vs `{`/${item.slug}`}` or do I simply write in a nested if then statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ternary in the prop value should give you what you need:

```
<li key={item.title}>
  {item.child_items 
    ? <Link 
        activeClassName="active"
        partiallyActive={true}
        aria-haspopup="true" 
        to={item.title === 'home' ? '/' : `/${item.slug}`}
      >
        {item.title}
      </Link>

    : <Link to={`/${item.slug}`}>{item.title}</Link>
  }
</li>
```

---

However, when logic gets complicated, it's a good indication you should move something to it's own component where it's easier to write as much code as you cleanly need to to make something work.

```
function NavLink({item}) {
  const toHref = item.title === 'home' ? '/' : `/${item.slug}`

  if (item.child_items) {
    // Link with children
    return <li>
      <Link 
        activeClassName="active"
        partiallyActive={true}
        aria-haspopup="true" 
        to={toHref}
      >
        {item.title}
      </Link>
    <li>
  } else {
    // Link with no children
    return <li><Link to={toHref}>{item.title}</Link></li>
  }  
}
```

Now you can just:

```
<NavLink item={item} key={item.title} />
```

And you know it's going to do the right thing.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank for for the additional information too.  It scratches an itch and i'll try it out.